# What was the bad guy's supervillain name in The Amazing Spider-Man?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

I'm not referring to the "human" name or birth certificate name of the scientist, but did the bad guy have a moniker like all of the other bad guys and vigilantes?

Like... Lizardman?

Comment: I'm not usually a big stickler for doing a lot of research before asking a question... but really?

Comment: @DCShannon I read the DVD box

Comment: LOL, okay. Before I criticize someone for lack of research, I go to Google and check real quick. I typed in "amazing spider man villain", and the autocomplete suggested "amazing spider man villain lizard". *Above* the search results is a blurb from Wikipedia: "On October 11, 2010, Rhys Ifans was confirmed to be the unnamed villain, and two days later his character was revealed to be Dr. Curt Connors / The Lizard. Arad said that Lizard is his favorite Spider-Man villain, and he had long wanted to use him in a film." Just saying.

Comment: @DCShannon I'm an old man. I don't know all of your fancy internet websites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Lizard

[image]

The villain was Curt Connors, played by Rhys Ifans. In the comics, this character is known as the Lizard, as [explained here](http://marvel.com/universe/Lizard_(Curtis_Connors)).

From a transcript:

> CURT CONNORS: Welcome, my name is **Dr. Curtis Connors**. And yes, in case you're
>   wondering, I'm a southpaw.

Comment: Argh, beat me to it :)

Comment: Good answer but I must say the name The Lizard reflects a remarkable lack of creativity lol. I'll mark this as correct when enough time has passed to do so.

Comment: While no one refers to him by *name* as "The Lizard", a number of characters refer to him as "the lizard" in the movie.

Comment: @Hack-R when he transforms into The Lizard, he's pretty much an animal. So he never really gives himself a cool name like other villains would. He's a big lizard, so people just call him _The Lizard_.

Comment: @Daft Right on. I just would've thought the newspaper might've given him a cool name. Maybe "Dino Death" or "Scaley Scaler" (since he scaled buildings) or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The film's director (Mark Webb) has confirmed in a number of interviews that the character in the film you're referring to is **[The Lizard](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/lizard/4005-1488/)**. He's also spoken to why he decided to include him as the film's primary antagonist...

> **SR:** *Were you the one to select the Lizard as the central villain and what inspired that choice?*
>
> **MW:** *“I’d always been a fan of the Lizard. In the world that were creating, I feel like the Lizard embodies, literally, one of the more
> important themes of the movie which is that we all have a missing
> piece. Right? Curt Connors is missing his arm, Peter is missing his
> parents and how you choose to fill that void is how you define
> yourself. And they make different pathways that become more apparent
> as the movie progresses but that was one of the things that I thought
> was particularly symmetrical about that villain. And the other thing
> is that he’s Peter’s friend in a way. Which gives Peter another set of
> problems he has to overcome. You can’t just kill the villain without
> some sort of emotional consequence.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview: Marc Webb Talks ‘The Amazing Spider-Man,’ The Lizard & ‘The Untold Story’](http://screenrant.com/the-amazing-spiderman-marc-webb-interview-rothc-159775/)</sup></sub>

...and the reason why he selected the 'look' of the Lizard from the older serials, rather than the most recent ("snouted") version.

> **Question:** *Can you talk a little about just bringing the Lizard to life and technically how you accomplished it? I imagine it was all
> motion capture?*
>
> **Marc Webb:** *There’s a lot that goes into it. I mean there was… When we shot those sequences we actually shot a human, a rather large…
> There was a combination of things. There was a guy named “Big John,”
> who was literally this big guy named John who did a lot of the
> interactive stuff, because when you are trying to interact with
> Andrew, with “Peter,” you need someone grabbing him to do those things
> and then we would replace him with the computer generated Lizard. But
> then the performance capture was done with Rhys and that was we would
> shoot Rhys in a similar environment and get his facial components,
> (Laughs) which we are still working on. **I actually just came from
> SPI trying to incorporate his performance into the Lizard itself. That
> takes an enormous amount of time and it’s tricky. In the comics
> there’s different incarnations of the Lizard. There’s the one with the
> snout, and I was interested more with something that could relate
> human emotions, because I wanted to keep Rhys’s performance in that
> creature and I was interested in.** You know performance; Pixar does
> it extremely well like creating the emotional qualities within
> characters that are essentially computer generated. So Rhys’s
> performance, getting that nuance and getting those ticks and the looks
> and creating an armature that can actually speak and lips that make
> sounds… (Laughs) It’s a very detailed and tedious process, but I
> really wanted him to have emotion. I wanted him to have a face and
> have a feeling and that’s the way I chose to do that and then there’s
> the physical components of it, where I wanted to make him very
> powerful. I wanted to make him stronger than Spiderman, that’s a
> really important part of it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview: ‘The Amazing Spider-Man’ Director Marc Webb](http://www.slashfilm.com/interview-the-amazing-spiderman-director-marc-webb/)</sup></sub>